Gitlab highlight tabs in diff
When having a look at changes in a MR, GitLab highlights any modified lines by a pair of light red/green lines, with the actual changes marked in a darker shade. Example for whitespace removal:

But GitLab appears to not be able to highlight tabs (tested with large indented code blocks). Example from some larger indented code blocks (line numbers change due to some added lines before the indented blocks):


Is there any setting where this behavior can be changed, such that tabs are highlighted similar to any other partial changes (such as the whitespace example) in a line?
